# BLE support in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth

How can I know if my computer supports BLE, I wrote simple applications on Arduino using this [board](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1697), now I want to write the same application but on my ubuntu computer, I read that Bluez which is installed by default supports BLE, but is there some special hardware I need to get like a dongle maybe? or it comes prebuilt in my computer.

My computer: ubuntu 14.04n lenovog510

Edit: I found the solution at https://askubuntu.com/questions/591803/how-to-check-bluetooth-version-on-my-laptop.
typing:

```
hciconfig -a
```

then cheking HCI Version, mine says 0x7 that's version 4.1 so my computer supports BLE.

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question within your question, BLE is part of Bluetooth 4.0 and higher as you basically stated. What is your question? A quick Google search can verify the standard.

Comment: yes I did not search deep enough before posting the question, I am keeping it for lazy people like me.